# Using SJXP to parse attribute value AND node value into the same userobject

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sjxp

I was trying to utilize [Simple Java XML Parser (SJXP)](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/simple-java-xml-parser-sjxp/) but ran into problems with the XML I need to parse into a data class.

### Data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE SYSTEM "local-1.2.2.dtd" >
<data>
    <article>
        <field name="name" type="text">HOTELS</field>
        <field name="name_de" type="text">HOTELS</field>
        <field name="name_zh" type="text">酒店</field>
        <field name="color" type="text">6,68,109,0.85</field>
        <field name="textcolor" type="text">255,255,255,1</field>
    </article>
 <!-- 20000 more articles ... -->
</data>
```

I was trying to do it that way:

### XmlHandler.java

```
private Map<String, Category> categoryMap;

private XMLParser<Category> categoryParser = new XMLParser<Category>(
        new DefaultRule<Category>(IRule.Type.CHARACTER, "/data/article") {
            @Override
            public void handleParsedCharacters(XMLParser<Category> parser, String text, Category category) {

                Log.d("XmlHandler", "Hello");
                if (category != null) {
                    categoryMap.put(category.getName(Category.LANG.EN), category);
                    Log.d("XmlHandler", "Saved category to map. New count="+categoryMap.values().size());
                    category.reset();
                } else {
                    category = new Category();
                    Log.d("XmlHandler", "Creating a new category");
                }
            }
        },
        new CategoryNameRule()
);


private class CategoryNameRule extends DefaultRule<Category> {

    private String nameKey = "";

    public CategoryNameRule() {
        super(Type.ATTRIBUTE, "/data/article/field", "name");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleParsedAttribute(XMLParser parser, int index,
                                      String value, Category category) {
        nameKey = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleParsedCharacters(XMLParser parser, String text, Category category) {

        Log.d("XmlHandler", "Handling nameKey="+nameKey);

        if(nameKey == null || nameKey.length() == 0){
            return;
        }else if( "name".equals(nameKey)){
           category.setName(Category.LANG.EN, text);
        }else if( "name_de".equals(nameKey)){
           category.setName(Category.LANG.DE, text);
        }else if( "name_zh".equals(nameKey)){
           category.setName(Category.LANG.ZH, text);
        }else if( "color".equals(nameKey)){
           category.colorBackground = getConvertedColor(text);
        }else if( "textcolor".equals(nameKey)){
           category.colorForeground = getConvertedColor(text);
        }

    }
}
```

Problem is that my hashmap turns out empty after the whole document is parsed and I don't know why. My guess is that I'd a combination of IRule.Type.CHARACTER & IRule.Type.ATTRIBUTE but I don't know to achieve that.

Any ideas/experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

Stefan,
I am so sorry for missing this question (just found it by accident via Google while I was searching for something else).

There are a few points of confusion here, so let me clarify, and then outline how I would recommend solving this (assuming you didn't find a way, but I realize this was 3 months ago)

First, you are correct, you need a combination of CHARACTER rules and ATTRIBUTE rules. The CHARACTER rules will give you the content *between* tags, for example:

```
<tag>this is CHARACTER data</tag>
```

Second, your rules should target tags that contain data you need, in your example above, it looks like you don't get any differentiating data until you get to the /data/article/field level (individual fields contain both ATTRIBUTES and CHARACTERS that you want)

It *does* looks like you key off of  (open tags) to tell when you have entered a new article so you know you are collecting field information for a specific, unique article. In that case you can actually use TAG rules to file when you hit a start tag, so you can do some logic like creating a new record in your HashMap for the soon-to-be-parsed new article.

Lastly, the *Category* argument you have being passed to the handlers is a *pass-through* user-variable.

What that means is you can call the Parse method:

```
XMLParser<List<Article>> p = new XMLParser<List<Article>>(... stuff ...);
List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();

p.parse(input, articleList);
```

this allows ALL your handlers to have direct access to your articleList so they can parse/store information directly in it, so when the call to parse(...) returns, you know your list is current and updated.

If you do not pass anything to the parse method in the userObject field, then the handlers will all receive a *null* argument.

Your use checking for *Category* had me confused and made me think you were expecting to get a changing value there when the handlers were called, which isn't the case. I just wanted to clarify that.

**Summary**

I think your perfect parser design would include 3 rules:

- /data/article TAG rule -- do something when a START article tag is encountered (and optionally when a CLOSE article tag is).
- /data/article/field CHARACTER rule -- store the parsed character data for the field.
- /data/article/field ATTRIBUTE rule -- store the parsed attribute data for the field.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Do I understand correctly I have to iterate more than once over the list? (First find articles, then find articles matching X)

Comment: @StefanHoth You shouldn't _need_ to iterate over the file multiple times, just add as many rules to each path as you need to make full sense of the file on the first pass through. I guess I am confused why you asked that -- maybe I'm missing a detail in your request that I didn't answer above. Can you clarify why you thought you would need to iter on the file multiple times to parse all the articles?